# Intercepting Restkit mapping before it is stored in Core Data

Tags: restkit

What is the correct way to update an object coming from the server before it is stored in Core Data? I have a class with "local" attributes I have to update before it is stored.

I have a class in my model

```
@interface classA : NSManagedObject {}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber* customAttribute;

@end
```

The value `customAttribute` is not in the JSON, it must be assigned a special value before the object is stored in CD. I display the JSON content in my `UITableView`s, but before the `NSFetchedResultsController` is notified, I need to have the value `customAttribute` initialized.

**UPDATE**: One possible solution could be using [Key Value Validation](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping#key-value-validation):

I have used the validation methods this way:

```
- (BOOL)validateEntityId:(inout __autoreleasing id *)ioValue error:(out NSError *__autoreleasing *)outError {

    self.customAttribute = [[AppConfiguration sharedInstance].sortIndexes objectForKey:*ioValue];

    if(self.customAttribute == nil) {

        self.customAttribute = @(9999);
    }

    return YES;
}
```

But when I run the application I get this exception:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Failed to process pending changes before save.  The context is still dirty after 1000 attempts.  Typically this recursive dirtying is caused by a bad validation method, -willSave, or notification handler.

I have also excluded the `customAttribute` attribute from mapping. But still I get the exception. (*Mapping exclusion/inclusion is not relevant to the solution.*)

**UPDATE 2:**

The validating method should assign values just to the `*ioValue`. It should not change any other value from the class or superclass but it can assign a value from a different already initialised class property.

Comment: You're going to need to post some code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The KVC validation approach should work, you just need to ensure that you aren't always dirtying the object by firing the change notifications when you don't (or shouldn't be) making changes.

At the moment your code:

```
self.customAttribute = [[AppConfiguration sharedInstance].sortIndexes objectForKey:*ioValue];

if(self.customAttribute == nil) {

    self.customAttribute = @(9999);
}
```

is always setting `self.customAttribute`, which fires the change notifications, then reading it back, which fires more notifications, and then potentially setting it again, yet more notifications.

Change this to use the primitive accessors to check if you need to make a change. If the new value equals the current value or you're going to set it to nil and then to something else, work that out first. Then, once you know what change to make - **if any** - make it.

Mostly, the point is to not make a change if you can help it as the repeated change is why you get a loop where the object is still dirty...

Comment: Thank you Wain. It is working for me. The Key Value Validation is exactly what I needed. I think this feature should be more emphasised in the documentation as it is very useful when working with Core Data.